# Is a muslim obliged to believe that magic exists?

Tags: quran, imaan, sihr

In Qur'an , it is told ( I don't remember exact verses but I am sure that it exists.) stating about prophet(s) like Musa ( Moses ) and Suleiman ( Solomon) that they came with miracles to counter magic and guide humanity with the message of God.

However, atleast in this progressing era, magic is (commonly) believed to be just a game of illusion and tricks. Many magicians and there tricks have been debunked. So , is a muslim necessarily obliged to believe that magic exists as something supernatural and it's not just visual and others type of tricking of gullible people ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is necessary to believe in whatever the Quran says, and to deny or doubt even a single verse is kufr. However the reality or reason behind the *effects* of sihr is something which is not explicitly mentioned in the Quran, rather it is subject to interpretation and on this there exist different views:

The majority of the Ahl al-Sunnah hold that there are different types of magic and that there is a type which has a reality beyond tricks and illusions. However some scholars have negated its reality, such as [Abu Bakr al-Jassas](https://shamela.ws/book/23579/50) and [Baghawy](https://quran.ksu.edu.sa/tafseer/baghawy/sura2-aya102.html) and some others.

Comment: Thanks . Does it mean that magic as a supernatural thing instead of tricking is not necessarily the right interpretation of Quran ?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't understand arabic and I read translations :( But thanks for link , I might learn it soon and read it that time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact answer to your question, but I think Muslims should believe In what was mentioned in the Quran, that there were supernaturals prophets sometimes used to convince their people and sometimes they were gifts they got from god like the ability of Sulaiman to talk to Jinn and Animals.

> And [one day] there were assembled before Solomon his hosts of invisible beings,  and of men, and of birds; and then they were led forth in orderly ranks. Quran 27:17

We should believe that Moses have done something super-natural (let's call it real magic) and that's why the magicians of the pharaoh believed in him because they as the most knowledgeable people about magic have seen something different and more powerful (doesn't matter if they were practicing something supernatural themselves or not)

> Thus truth was confirmed, and all that they did was made of no effect. So they were defeated there and returned disgraced. And the sorcerers fell down prostrate. Quran 7:119

I personally have met hundreds of people who believe that their ancestors could talk to Jinn and do supernaturals, I don't believe it's true yet I think somehow our ancestors were more connected with the unknown world (the unseen, the heavens ..) because they had more stable, spiritual and clean life and I can see that in my mom's dreams and how they mostly come true, this is something supernatural for me that I cannot deny because I have seen it since I was a child.

And talking about dreams, there is a well-known respected western scholar (Carl Jung) who has a spiritual point of view about them:

[Carl Jung Talk - The World Within. The Power Of Imagination.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AjgEOLocrus&ab_channel=SpiritualMind)

Comment: Thanks. But I think that it will happen in future also that our generations will say these about us. Problem is that they don't exist when we search them and appears in legends , myths and books later ;)

Comment: got you, but i think there is a difference between what myths say, and the fact that supernaturals exist according to the Quran, GOD, himself is supernatural for our world! 
Is magic one of them, what is the limit of magic, I don't know. it was mentioned in the Quran so I believe in it without details, but I am open to possibilities if someone can prove his idea about it!